# Multistage manufacturing and sales model in graph

Tags: r, igraph

Here's a simplified reproducible example of a companies manufacturing and sales flow model with graph in R.

```
library(igraph)

# Create graph
graph= graph.formula(
  R --+ P1,
  P1 --+ M1,
  R --+ P2,
  P2 --+ M2,
  P1 --+ P3,
  P2 --+ P3,
  P3 --+ M2,
  R --+ P4,
  P3 --+ P5,
  P4 --+ P5,
  P5 --+ M3,
  P5 --+ M4
  )

# Change colors for pretty plot
V(graph)$color= "gray"
V(graph)[name== "R"]$color= "cyan"
V(graph)[grepl(x= name, pattern= "M")]$color= "green"
V(graph)[name %in% c("P1", "P2", "P4")]$color= "red"

# Add sales volume as attribute and add to edge label in plot
E(graph)[4]$sales= 100
E(graph)[4]$label= paste("Sales:\n", E(graph)[4]$sales, "tons")
E(graph)[6]$sales= 200
E(graph)[6]$label= paste("Sales:\n", E(graph)[6]$sales, "tons")
E(graph)[8]$sales= 500
E(graph)[8]$label= paste("Sales:\n", E(graph)[8]$sales, "tons")
E(graph)[11]$sales= 1000
E(graph)[11]$label= paste("Sales:\n", E(graph)[11]$sales, "tons")
E(graph)[12]$sales= 2000
E(graph)[12]$label= paste("Sales:\n", E(graph)[12]$sales, "tons")

# Add bill of material share as attribute and add to edge label in plot
E(graph)[1:3]$share= 1.0
E(graph)[1:3]$label= paste("Share:\n", E(graph)[1:3]$share*100, "%")
E(graph)[7]$share= 0.8
E(graph)[7]$label= paste("Share:\n", E(graph)[7]$share*100, "%")
E(graph)[5]$share= 1 - 0.8
E(graph)[5]$label= paste("Share:\n", E(graph)[5]$share*100, "%")
E(graph)[9]$share= 0.4
E(graph)[9]$label= paste("Share:\n", E(graph)[9]$share*100, "%")
E(graph)[10]$share= 1 - 0.4
E(graph)[10]$label= paste("Share:\n", E(graph)[10]$share*100, "%")

# Add preliminary NA vol attribute to nodes and add label in plot
V(graph)$vol= NA
V(graph)$label= paste(V(graph)$name, "\nVolume:\n", V(graph)$vol, "tons")

# Plot
E(graph)$label.cex=0.8
V(graph)$label.cex=0.8
V(graph)$size=20
layout= layout.reingold.tilford(graph, root=1)
layout[3,2]=0
layout[5,2]=0
plot(graph, layout= layout)
```

[image]

The model network comprises of following components:

- `R`: Raw material in cyan color needed to made products `P1, P2, P4`.
- `P1...P5`: Products in red color been made in one step out of `R` directly (`P1, P2, P4`) or as multi-stage manufactured products (`P3, P5`). Each product has a bill of material with a recipe.
- `M...`: Markets in green color to which the products `P1...5` are sold to. The only exception is `P4` which is not sold, it's just made to serve as precursor for `P5` (in combination which `P3`).

Known attributes to edges in this network are:

- `Sales`: Sales volume in tons of `P1, P2, P3, P5` to markets `M1, M2, M3, M4`.
- Recipe `Share`: The amount of precursor in % needed to make a specific product. Example: To make 1ton of `P1, P2, P4` 1ton raw material is needed (therefore share 100%). To make 10tons `P3` 8tons (=80%) `P2` and 2tons (=20%) `P1` is needed.

**I am looking for a solution to calculate the volume attributes `vol` for nodes product `P1 ... P5` and raw material `R`. Currently they are set to `NA`. `vol` shall be consistent to sold volumes and the share of product recipes.**

*Comment: I am looking for a generalized solution which works for this simplified example but also for the more complicated (more nodes and more manufacturing stages) real world model. I was thinking about a kind of multistage propagation algorithm. First `sales` data would be aggregated to result in product vertex `vol` attribute of products being sold to markets. Then another step would calculate upstream on basis of `share` the requirements to make the products to yield volumes from previous step and so on. A generalized solution exceeds my `R` knowledge. Any ideas how to accomplish the task ?*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After lot's of experimentation, looks like I have a first solution. The reproducible example can be solved with it. So far haven't yet tested in the real world complicated case.

**1. Recode the task a bit:**

```
library(igraph)

# Create graph
graph= graph.formula(
  R --+ P1,
  P1 --+ M1,
  R --+ P2,
  P2 --+ M2,
  P1 --+ P3,
  P2 --+ P3,
  P3 --+ M2,
  R --+ P4,
  P3 --+ P5,
  P4 --+ P5,
  P5 --+ M3,
  P5 --+ M4
  )

# Change colors for pretty plot
V(graph)$color= "gray"
V(graph)[name== "R"]$color= "cyan"
V(graph)[grepl(x= name, pattern= "M")]$color= "green"
V(graph)[name %in% c("P1", "P2", "P4")]$color= "red"

# Add sales volume as attribute and add to edge label in plot
E(graph)$vol= NA # prefill
E(graph)[4]$vol= 100
E(graph)[6]$vol= 200
E(graph)[8]$vol= 500
E(graph)[11]$vol= 1000
E(graph)[12]$vol= 2000

# Add bill of material share as attribute and add to edge label in plot
E(graph)[1:3]$share= 1.0
E(graph)[7]$share= 0.8
E(graph)[5]$share= 1 - 0.8
E(graph)[9]$share= 0.4
E(graph)[10]$share= 1 - 0.4

# Add preliminary NA vol attribute to nodes and add label in plot
V(graph)$vol= 0

# Plot
update.labels= function(graph){
  E(graph)[4]$label= paste("Vol:\n", E(graph)[4]$vol, "tons")
  E(graph)[6]$label= paste("Vol:\n", E(graph)[6]$vol, "tons")
  E(graph)[8]$label= paste("Vol:\n", E(graph)[8]$vol, "tons")
  E(graph)[11]$label= paste("Vol:\n", E(graph)[11]$vol, "tons")
  E(graph)[12]$label= paste("Vol:\n", E(graph)[12]$vol, "tons")
  E(graph)[1:3]$label= paste("Share:\n", E(graph)[1:3]$share*100, "%", "\nVol:\n", E(graph)[1:3]$vol, "tons")
  E(graph)[7]$label= paste("Share:\n", E(graph)[7]$share*100, "%", "\nVol:\n", E(graph)[7]$vol, "tons")
  E(graph)[5]$label= paste("Share:\n", E(graph)[5]$share*100, "%", "\nVol:\n", E(graph)[5]$vol, "tons")
  E(graph)[9]$label= paste("Share:\n", E(graph)[9]$share*100, "%", "\nVol:\n", E(graph)[9]$vol, "tons")
  E(graph)[10]$label= paste("Share:\n", E(graph)[10]$share*100, "%", "\nVol:\n", E(graph)[10]$vol, "tons")
  V(graph)$label= paste(V(graph)$name, "\nVolume:\n", V(graph)$vol, "tons")
  graph
}
graph= update.labels(graph)
E(graph)$label.cex=0.8
V(graph)$label.cex=0.8
V(graph)$size=20
layout= layout.reingold.tilford(graph, root=1)
layout[3,2]=0
layout[5,2]=0
plot(graph, layout= layout)
```

[image]

**Solution:**

```
# Aggregate sales volumes to markets
this.vertices.names= V(graph)[grepl(x=name, pattern = "M")]$name
for (i in this.vertices.names) {
  V(graph)[name== i]$vol= sum(E(graph)[to(i)]$vol, na.rm=T)
}

# Calculate volumes along the network
# do stepwise from farthest nodes to nearest (origin is "R")
# 1.step: aggregate "from" edge vol attributes to product node vol attribute
# 2.step: distribute node vol attribute to "to" edge vol attribute by vol of node * share of edge 

# Function to sort nodes even if they have same distance from root
max.out.edges= function(graph, from.node.name) {
  max(shortest.paths(graph= graph, v= V(graph)[name==from.node.name], mode="out")
      [is.finite(shortest.paths(graph= graph, v= V(graph)[name==from.node.name], mode="out"))]) 
}

# Function to create a list of nodes lists sorted with decending distance from root
list.farthest.nodes= function(graph, from.node.name) {
  ans= list()
  sp= shortest.paths(graph= graph, v= V(graph)[name==from.node.name], mode="out")
  max.distance= max(sp[is.finite(sp)])  
  for (i in 0:max.distance-1) {
    nodes= sapply(dimnames(sp)[[2]][which(sp==max.distance-i)], function(x) max.out.edges(graph, x), simplify= T)
    ans= c(ans, list (names(nodes[order(nodes)])))
  }
  ans[[1]]= NULL
  ans[[max.distance+1]]= "R"
  ans
}


farthest.nodes= list.farthest.nodes(graph, "R")

for (i in farthest.nodes) {
  print(paste("Levels:", i))
  for (j in i) {
    print(paste("Single Level",j))
    if (!grepl(x=j, pattern="M")) {
      V(graph)[name== j]$vol= V(graph)[name== j]$vol + sum(E(graph)[from(j)]$vol, na.rm=T)
      if (!grepl(x=j, pattern="R")) {
        E(graph)[to(j)]$vol= E(graph)[to(j)]$share * V(graph)[name== j]$vol        
      }
    }
  }  
}

graph= update.labels(graph); plot(graph, layout=layout)
```

[image]